# Why does voltage go in one direction and not both?

Tags: voltage, led, transistors

Hello I have this inverter circuit I made that is connected to a button when the button is on one led is on and the other is off and vice-versa.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3rR1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What should happen is that when the button is pressed voltage flow to one led AND to the transistor base, but it only goes to the transistor base. What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks for the help everyone but I found a solution ill post it for people with the same problem in the future. I used a resistor calculator I found on the web and changed R3 to 150 ohms, removed R5 and added a 330 ohm resistor before D1. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Replace D1 with a resistor in the 1k to 10k range. The sum of the voltage drops of your D1 + the base-emitter of Q1 is less than the voltage required to turn D3 on.

Comment: Just to clarify, voltage does not "flow". Voltage is a *difference* in potential between two points. *Current* is what flows.

Comment: And 'normal' circuit-drawing convention has the ground/negative voltage rail at the bottom - it just makes your circuit easier to decipher.

Answer (score 7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3PSrd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's how to draw the circuit.

- Positive rail at the top.
- Negative rail at the bottom.
- Current flow from top to bottom.
- Inputs on left.
- Outputs on right.

Power flow, logic and schema becomes much simpler.

Comment: clear post and helpful to the OP. Hope they don't design every circuit without an R2 from here on :-) Good post.

Answer (score 2):

> What should happen is that when the button is pressed voltage flow to one led AND to the transistor base, but it only goes to the transistor base. **What am I doing wrong?**

All. Or better, the lack of a solid foundation of electrical engineering is the worst thing. 
**Voltage don't flow!** Current flow.